# The number of double coset of p-group $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, p-groups

Following this question: [Question about orbits of the left translation of group action](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4785144/question-about-orbits-of-the-left-translation-of-group-action)

> Let $H$ be proper subgroups of the group $G$. For each $x \in G$ define the $H$ *double coset* of $x$ in $G$ to be the set
> $$HxH = \{hxk \, | \, h \in H, k \in H\}.$$

**Question**: Suppose that $H$ is a proper subgroup. I am working to show that the number of double cosets of $H$ in $G$, which are left cosets of $H$ in $G$ is at least $p$.

My proof:

Following the comments, I wrote a proof as follows. Note that the number of "double cosets=left cosets" is just same as the number of $HxH=xH$, which is  the number of $N:=\{g\in G: gHg^{-1}=H\}$.

Consider the group action: $G\times H\to H$ by conjugation. Then the number of stabilizers of this action is the same as the number of normalizer, which is divisible by the order of $G$ with some power of $p$.

Moreover, by class equation, we know that the center $C(H)$ of $H$ is not trivial (see [Centralizer not trivial.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3622594/centralizer-not-trivial)). Then $C(H)\subset N$, $N$ is also non-trivial. Thus, the order of $N$ is at least $p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to count the number of left cosets $xH$ in $G/H$ such that $xH=HxH$. Let $$H'=\{x\in G:xH=HxH\}.$$
It is easy to check that $H'$ is a group containing the group $H$. It suffices to show that $H'\ne H$
because then $|H':H|\ge p$, so there are at least $p$ distinct cosets $xH$ with $x\in H'$.

We prove the required claim by induction on $|G|$ as follows.
Suppose that $|G|=p$. Since $H$ is a proper subgroup of $G$, $H=\{e\}$, so there are exactly $p$ one-element left cosets $xH$ and each of them is double.

Suppose that the claim is proved for all $p$-groups with smaller orders than $|G|$.
Let $Z$ be the center of $H$. Clearly, $Z\subset H'$. So if $Z\not\subset H$ then we are done.
Thus we suppose that $Z\subset H$.
Then $H/Z$ is a proper subgroup of $G/Z$.
It is well-known (see, for instance [Lan, I.6.$\S 3$]) that $Z\ne\{e\}$, so $|G/Z|<|G|$.
By the inductive hypothesis, there exists a class $\bar x\in G/Z\setminus H/Z$ such that $\bar x (H/Z)=(H/Z)\bar x (H/Z)$.
Let $x$ be any element of $\bar x Z$. Then $x\not\in H$, but $HxH\subset H\bar xH \subset \bar xH=xH,$ so $x\in H'$.

*References*

[Lan] Serge Lang, *Algebra*, Addison-Wesley, Reading, Mass., 1965 (Russian translation, Moskow, 1968).